# Which sounds better on a CV?

Tags: resume

I need to publish a research article on my institution's website. Grad student coauthored with a PhD professor. Not in a student-tutor sense but rather we coauthored it as a research paper. It can be published under the following categories:

Monograph (Technical report)

Monograph (Project report)

Monograph (Working paper)

Monograph (Discussion paper)

Monograph (Unspecified)

Which of these, seen on a CV, would be more impressive in a general sense. Remember that it is student coauthored with professor, so I am wary of project report (which sounds like a student assignment) for this reason. Working paper could also sound like it's just a work document. My point is which of these elicits the best response in someone who is unfamiliar with academic terminology, who would read it on a resume, for an unrelated post.

In reality it is a research paper, but it has to be published under one of those categories.

Comment: As someone unfamiliar with academic terminology, I have no idea what any of those mean and have no response without more context. Why not just say what you did?

Comment: @SethR It is a research paper. But I cannot publish it under that category, it has to be one of the above mentioned categories. Given that I want to link to it on my CV, I'm trying to optimize for the best possible impression.

Comment: From my perspective, it wouldn’t make a bit of difference because I know what a monograph is, and that’s as much detail as I need on a resume. I would probably ask you more about it if I interviewed you. Why do you think its classification is important?

Comment: Perhaps this would be a better question for Academia SE (https://academia.stackexchange.com/). I'm not sure the average workplace would know or care what the different categories mean.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question will get better answers if it is asked on https://academia.stackexchange.com/ (assuming it conforms to their rules).

Comment: If you're targeting your resume outside of academia, then have a heading under your work (or education) history - "Papers and scholarly works" - then list the title, a very brief summary, and a link/reference to where you published it. Don't use those titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Working Paper sounds like it's for an unfinished project
- Discussion Paper doesn't sound very impressive, it's just some points for people to discuss in a meeting
- Unspecified is just unspecified!

So that leaves

- Technical Report sounds better of you're going to work in some technical field
- Project Report at least sounds like you've finished a project.
  So take your pick of those two.

Comment: This is very much biased by your personal experience with those terms. “Working Paper” is perfectly respectable in places dealing with research because it means that you may have an idea interesting enough to release a preliminary paper to get feedback from your peers. The correct advice is to classify the paper based on what it actually is instead of what sounds the most important to people who don’t know the terminology.

Comment: @SimonB Exactly the kind of answer I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @ColleenV "This is very much biased by your personal experience with those terms" - absolutely true!  But the OP is asking about bigging up their CV.

Comment: There’s a reason why overly subjective questions are off-topic on Stack Exchange sites. If everyone’s opinion is an equally valid answer, the question should be closed until it can be reworked into something less subjective. Is there any reason to believe that your opinion would be shared by the person hiring the OP? We don’t even know who they anticipate sending this resume to…